# Dynamics CRM How to tell which products are part of a bundle in C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I have a program that bills a customer based on a custom entity. It is a subscription based process. We enter an order, if that order has a product that has been defined as a subscription product then the custom entity is created. The product can be either a single product or it can be a bundle. When the subscription ends I need to end the ability of the customer to continue to use the software.

I can read the product and I can determine if the product is a bundle by examining the attribute "productstructure". How do I determine which products are included in the bundle?

Thanks

Comment: I ask a specific question so I'm not sure why someone voted to close the question. But in either case I figured it out.

Comment: Not sure either. I was just asking the same question. I thought it was useful - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you retrieve the product you can use "productstructure" to determine if it is a bundle. If the value is a 3 it is a bundle.

You can then query the "productassociation" table where the attribute "productid" equals the Id of the bundle.

The attribute you need to retrieve from the "prodctassociation" table is "associatedproduct". You then retrieve the product instance.

```
QueryExpression productBundleQuery = new QueryExpression();
productBundleQuery.Distinct = false;
productBundleQuery.EntityName = "productassociation";
productBundleQuery.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("associatedproduct");
productBundleQuery.Criteria = new FilterExpression
{
     Conditions = { new ConditionExpression("productid", ConditionOperator.Equal, bundle.Id) }
};

EntityCollection productBundleCollection = _service.RetrieveMultiple(productBundleQuery);

foreach (Entity productAssociation in productBundleCollection.Entities)
{
    Entity product = _service.Retrieve("product", ((EntityReference)productAssociation["associatedproduct"]).Id, new ColumnSet("name", ...));

    Do something....
 }
```